# Mysql - Update timestamp from_unixtime deletes the row

Tags: mysql, perl

If I run a the following SQL the row will vanish:

```
update t set
ts = from_unixtime(13933210)
where id = 3978947
```

Field is configured as:

```
  `pollTs` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I have tried removing the indexes and the result is still the same.

My MySQL is 5.5.28

Thanks

*update* only occurs via a PERL DBI DBD MYSQL client

```
my $id =  $dbh->last_insert_id( undef, undef, undef, undef );
my $sql = "update nodePerf set
            ts = ?
            where id = $id";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($ts);
```

This occurs when from_unixtime and a string.

Comment: Any triggers on the table? An update doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Hello, no triggers. Isolated to the PERL client now.

Comment: 1) The SQL you show in your first snippet doesn't match the second snippet. Why? 2) There are a [long list of caveats](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#last_insert_id) associated with `last_insert_id`. Do you do an insert immediately before calling it? Please show that. 3) Why do you use a placeholder for `ts` but not for `id`? Have you checked the value of `id`? 4) You don't show where you get `$ts` in your second snippet. Please show all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working for me

```
create table t(date_entered timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

SELECT * FROM t;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO t VALUES();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM t;
+---------------------+
| date_entered        |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-30 17:55:56 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE t SET date_entered = from_unixtime(13933210) ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM t;
+---------------------+
| date_entered        |
+---------------------+
| 1970-06-11 11:50:10 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are right it works if I use the CLI.

However if I use my PERL DBI client it deletes the row.

This occurs if I even use a basic string.

Comment: So whats the issue if it is working from CLI, it would work from any where

Comment: It deletes the row in PERL but yes on the CLI it works.

Could it be a session variable?

I've updated the post to include the PERL code.

Comment: Couldn't replicate apart from my script. Given up and changed my design. This answer clearly identified the root cause was not MySQL